# Remove iOS App that is Ready For Sale

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store-connect

My question is simple:
Is it possible to remove my app from iTunesConnect that is Ready For Sale?

I have submitted a buggy app and want to update it using different Mac. Accidentally i didn't backup my certificate and other important stuffs from my old Mac. So I think the only workaround is to submit new fresh app using different bundle name and SKU. The problem is how to remove my existing app from iTunesConnect that is Ready for Sale?

Comment: You don't need to submit a completely new app. Create a new certificate and then update your provisioning profiles with the new certificate. Install the new provisioning profiles into Xcode and rebuild. No need for a new bundle id.

Comment: should i revoke my certificate?

Comment: You can revoke the old one if you can since it sounds like you don't have access to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In iTunes Connect, click on

- Manage Your Apps
- (The App you want to remove)
- Rights & Purchasing
- then Deselect all countries
- Save

That will remove it from sale.

Answer (score 5):

2017 update

In Itunes connect

- My Apps
- select your app
- Pricing & Availability
- Under Availability , select Remove from sale
- Click Save

Answer (score 1):

If you click on your app, then click "Rights and Pricing", you can then select "Deselect All" in the country availability section below the pricing. This will remove your application from the app store in all countries, and you can change this back after you submit your new binary.

Answer (score 1):

**As of 2020 update**

Login in https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

My Apps -> Select your app

Then Click on **Pricing and Availability** tab from Left side panel.

Under Availability section, Select **Remove from sale**

Click Save

[image]